# Create javascript popup in function from Rails link_to call

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, popup, widget, link-to

I'm trying to create a standard javascript popup widget to provide hints across my Rails application.  I'm hoping to be able to create a single popup widget where the information contained inside changes whenever different hint buttons are clicked.  All of the samples I seem to find use the javascript onclick, but this won't allow me to pass in different text values based on which button was clicked.  Also, I keep seeing the popup being created using html rather than being done in the javascript.

This is working to call a javascript function

```
<%= f.label :name %><%= link_to image_tag("hint_link.jpeg", :size=>"13x13"), '#', :onclick => 'create_hint_widget("a"); return false;' %>
```

But I need to know how to create a popup widget from the called function, as

```
function hint_widget(hint_text) { create_popup_widget }
```

Maybe something like this?

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable().html("<div id='draggable' class='ui-widget-content'><p>hint_text</p></div>");
```

This was the best solution I've been able to come up with, but there may be better solutions.  I'm open for any advice/suggestions

Answer (score 0):

This is the basics of how you would start to construct a tooltip system - however there are thousands of already available so it does not make much sense to write one unless you are doing it to learn.

```js
$(function(){

  # delegate a handler to elements that have a `data-tooltip` attribute.
  $(document).on('click', 'a[data-tooltip]', function(){
    var $el = $(this)
    var $tooltip = $('<div class="tooltip-overlay">').text($el.data('tooltip'));
    $el.append($tooltip);
    # fade out and remove tooltip after 3s
    $tooltip.delay(3000).fadeOut(100).remove();
    return false;
  });
  
  # handle when user clicks a tooltip
  $(document).on('click', '.tooltip-overlay', function(){
    $(this).remove();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
a[data-tooltip] {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  top: -140%;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 
<p><a href="#">Link without tooltip</a></p>
<p><a href="#" data-tooltip="Sample text" class="tooltip">Link with tooltip</a></p>
```

- http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/tooltips.html
- http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips
- https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/